# How to run installer > 2GB on AIX without bash?

Tags: bash, sh, aix, filesize

I'm trying to install software on a AIX server that does not have bash.  The installer is greater than 2GB so sh won't work. The AIX Server is set with proper files system to allow files > 2GB and ulimits are set as they should.  And installer will run with bash but not with sh due to its size.  Is there some way to configure AIX so sh can install a file > 2GB like bash can?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Why doesn't `sh` work? What happens when you try? I'm not sure what would impose any sort of file-size limit (unless it's an AIX-specific thing).

Comment: chepner, It says "/bin/sh: : cannot open".  Its an Install Anywhere installer.  And its not related to permissions. And I'm sure its a AIX-specific thing.

Comment: The easiest thing is probably to install bash. Alternatively, compile a copy without installing it. If it's one of those installers with an embedded tarball you can manually extract it instead, but this requires reading and modifying the script which is not a simple or mechanical process

Comment: The AIX I used had `ksh` available, but I don't remember the exact path to get to `ksh93`, which would be the preferred version. But almost seems like an OS level limitation. What does `file /bin/sh` show. Does it indicate anything about 32-vs-64 bit versions? For that matter what does `file /path/to/InstallAnywhere/Installer` show? (Of course I mean the real path to the Installer program you're trying to run). Does that `file` info conflict with other info you have about your system OS and hardware? Good luck.

Comment: The company will not install bash for security reasons.  We have had this issue with several other customers and they just use bash and all is fine.  This is the first customer we have encountered that will not install bash.  It fails with ksh too.

Comment: You might also try /bin/ksh93 but most likely it won't work either -- these 32-bit programs were built without large-file-support in the previous millenia. Anyways, if they don't let you install bash, they won't allow you to run your installer script either.